# n-dimensional vector

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I want to declare a vector of a vector of a vector of a... (up to n dimensions).

Like so:

```
using namespace std;
// for n=2
vector<vector<int> > v2;
// for n=3
vector<vector<vector<int> > > v3;
// for n=4
vector<vector<vector<vector<int> > > > v3;
```

Is there a way to go about doing this for an arbitrary n with template metaprogramming?

Comment: [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, and it's pretty straightforward.

Much like a proof by induction, we set up a recursive case and a (partially specialized) base case that ends the recursion.

```
template<size_t dimcount, typename T>
struct multidimensional_vector
{
    typedef std::vector< typename multidimensional_vector<dimcount-1, T>::type > type;
};

template<typename T>
struct multidimensional_vector<0,T>
{
    typedef T type;
};

multidimensional_vector<1, int>::type v;
multidimensional_vector<2, int>::type v2;
multidimensional_vector<3, int>::type v3;
multidimensional_vector<4, int>::type v4;
```

Comment: I would suggest to use variadic template parameters instead of just one `T` in order to allow to pass other stuff to `std::vector` (it does take additional defaulted arguments).

Comment: @bitmask: No reason for variadic arguments, just one type argument for the Allocator, which should be given the same default as `std::vector` itself has.  But in the rare case a non-standard allocator is wanted, it probably will apply to all usage of this class, in which case it can just be put into the recursive typedef line.

Comment: Yes, but you would have to specify that manually, right? Seems like a lot of trouble.

Comment: How would you go about doing this if the number of dimensions is not static?

Comment: @JonDeaton: C++ is statically typed

Comment: @BenVoigt I know that...The dimension count in this example is static (i.e. must be known at compile time in order  for it to be used as a template parameter). If you tried to use a dynamic value for the number of dimensions in this example, you would get a compiler error. I am wondering if you have a suggestion for an N dimensional array where N is not `constexpr`.

Comment: @Jon: You should ask a separate question about that.  Specify whether you want rectangular or ragged dimensions.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good idea.