# in c++ how to declare 3D dimensional vector in a 3D dimensional vector

Tags: c++, boost, stl

How can I declare a 3D dimensional vector in C++ such that each element is in turn a 3d vector whose size I would in prior.

Comment: why not `std::vector`?

Comment: "A 3D vector in which each element is in turn a 3D vector" -- so you want a 9D vector then?

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury that would be a 6D vector

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C++11:

```
template <typename T>
using three_d_vector = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>;
template <typename T>
using six_d_vector = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<three_d_vector<T>>>>;
template <typename T>
using nine_d_vector = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<six_d_vector<T>>>>;
```

Then you'd use it like `nine_d_vector<int>`, or whatever type you're using. Note that this is just exactly the same as nesting `std:vector` nine times. Honestly, especially if you're doing this with various other dimensions, you might just want to use `n` dimensional vectors as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105514/n-dimensional-vector).

Comment: Whoops, this is a very good point. Edited.