# How to resize n-dimensional array using method in template class?

Tags: visual-c++, c++14

I want to create some class which let us do operations on n-dimensional vectors (finally my goal is having a tensor class). Firstly I used generation of data type of such tensors from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105514/n-dimensional-vector).

```
template<size_t dimcount, typename T>
struct multidimensional_vector
{
    typedef std::vector< typename multidimensional_vector<dimcount - 1, T>::type > type;
};

template<typename T>
struct multidimensional_vector<0, T>
{
    typedef T type;
};
```

After it, I create template of my class, which in simplified version looks as follow:

```
template<size_t _rank>
class Real_tensor
{
    using tensor_type = typename multidimensional_vector<_rank, double>::type;
private:
    size_t rank = _rank;
    size_t dimension = 0;
    tensor_type values;
public:
    Real_tensor(size_t);
    void create_empty_tensor();
    template <typename T> 
    void create_empty_subtensor(T&, size_t);
};
```

And here I have a problem with creating this empty tensor. It generates recursion of creating empty subtensors:

```
template<size_t _rank>
inline void Real_tensor<_rank>::create_empty_tensor()
{
    this->create_empty_subtensor(this->values,this->rank);   
}
```

This works, but that recursion:

```
template<size_t _rank>
template<typename T>
inline void Real_tensor<_rank>::create_empty_subtensor(T& sub_tensor,size_t subrank)
{
    if (subrank >= 1)
    {
        sub_tensor.resize(this->dimension);  
    }
    subrank--;
    if (subrank >= 1)
    {
        for (auto element : sub_tensor)
        {
            this->create_empty_subtensor(element, subrank);
        }
    }
}
```

not. It gives me error about data type - for example that I want to use `.resize()` on `double` which of course doesn't have such method.

I use C++14 in Visual Studio 2022.

I tried some other approaches but still, it gave error either about `vector` class or datatype of n-dimensional vector. I don't know what I should do.

Comment: `subrank` should be a template parameter, not a run-time parameter. And then you need either `if constexp` (requires C++17) or specialization (the same trick you used with `multidimensional_vector`) to avoid instantiating `create_empty_subtensor<double>` when the subrank is 1.